# Where does Juju store a log of all commands run and their output for each unit?

Tags: juju, output

Sometimes when deploying a service (and more specifically a new unit) for a Juju charm, an error occurs and there seems to be no way of finding out exactly what it was.

Is there some sort of output log of all commands the unit ran?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that each unit stores a log of the commands run in `/var/log/juju/unit/unit-service_name-service_number.log`. You can access it by taking advantage of Juju's `ssh` command like so:

`juju ssh service_name/service_number`

This will drop you into a shell for that unit. You can then use a text editor or even just `cat | less` to read the log.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `juju debug-log` to get a distributed log of all operations by all agents. It allows suppressing things by log level, so give `juju debug-log -h` a read. It does miss a few things, but for the most part it should give you what you are looking for.

The following command shows all the logs from the beginning of time. So it will also show the logs from **before you started `juju debug-log`**

```
juju debug-log --replay
```

Comment: But does this answer the question? I need the output of the commands *after* they are executed.

Comment: That is exactly what the debug-log provides.. output of all commands executed by all agents (hooks, API calls, everything). Charms can also control what log level their output is produced at by using 'juju-log'.

Comment: But does this return the output of commands that have run *before* I call `juju debug-log`?

Comment: No, debug-log informs the agents that they need to start sending their logs. If you want to see the logs of agent activities past you must login to each unit and inspect the logs in /var/log/juju and /var/lib/juju

Comment: Yes, that was the question I asked and the answer below contains that information.

Comment: `debug-log`, as far as I can tell, doesn't include hook output messages: I can see them in the `charm.log` on the instance but not in the debug log, even with `-l DEBUG`.

Comment: `juju debug-log --replay` shows all the logs, even those from *before* you call `juju debug-log`

Answer (score 1):

You can find the complete log inside the `data-dir` set in your `environments.yaml` file.

Open it with `gksudo <path_to_data-dir>`, navigate thru the folders to your `units` folder, open the service folder you want to have a look at and look at the `unit.log` file.